# how to handle the MySQL errors in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a following form in my application, and there is email field from which the data goes to email unique column in database table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiiJM.png)

The problem is that when i entry with duplicate data it will show me this following error page, instead i want to display 'duplicated entry' in the form field of email.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWHrQ.png)

Comment: First of all put your code here not images. Have you checked the inputs with validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel's [validations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique). When you are posting a form, in the controller :

```
<?php 

public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Assuming that the table name is users and the column name of email field is email_address
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'email|unique:users,email_address',
        'your_other_fields' => 'validationRules...'
    ]);

    // Your store logic here

}
```

Then in your frontend blade form, you need to add a block to show if this validation fails.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email *</label>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="enter email" name="email">
    @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

Now, in frontend if someone enters an existing email it will automatically show error. Please note, the key in the error is what you specify in `name=""` in the form and not the column name in the table.

Comment: Thank you so much it's work.

Answer (score 0):

before you submit the insert sql, you can use the select query and count if there is any value return or not. If value return, you can let the system show error else insert the data to database

or you can use try catch method to avoid the error happen